# Java - ValueChangeListener that changes its own value

Tags: java, user-interface, model, textbox, listener

In this situation, there is a textbox on which the value is checked.
If the value is lower than {minimumValue}, then this value set to {minimumValue}, which is taken from another table in the DB (it is accessed via a service, and cannot be hardcoded into the POJO).

A listener is placed on the textbox, however, this listener cannot change the value of its own textbox, because it accesses itself again and/or somehow decouples from the textbox it is placed on. In short, the listener cannot seem to change the value of its own textbox.

The value of the Model is changed, however the value displayed on the UI remains the same, unchanged.

I have tried the following:

```
private final class MyValueChangeListener implements IValueChangeListener {
    @Override
    public void handleValueChange(final ValueChangeEvent event) {
        this.detachAllListeners();
        this.handleMyValueChange();
        this.attachAllListeners();
    }
  }
```

However, it still does not work. Are there any ways of doing this?
Preferably, without having to access the refreshUI() method, which would be less elegant.

Comment: Are you programming for Eclipse?

Comment: I am not programming for Eclipse, but I am using an Eclipse IDE. 
I'm not sure how this is relevant.

Comment: `IValueChangeListener` and `ValueChangedEvent` are eclipse core classes.

Comment: you can add a boolean outside of the listener like boolean reset; and if it is true, have ur program change the value to the desired number and then set it back to false.

Comment: I see, you mean like a trigger?

And then have a listener on that boolean value.

Comment: Tried with a trigger, didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

This could not be done, ultimately, except by modifying the underlying model and then refreshing the whole UI.